# SIMR package - effect sizes

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm using SIMR package to estimate power and effect sizes of my models. I don't understand how the package estimates the effect sizes, though, and what kind of an effect it reports (is it Cohen's d?).

E.g.
For my model, in which AQ and LSAS are continuous predictors and cond is a categorical (3 level) predictor, I get this output (for AQ):

```
> model.cnv.cue = lme4::lmer(DV ~  AQ_centr  + cond + LSAS_centr + (1 | code), data = mydata, REML = FALSE)        
> powerSim(model.cnv.cue,nsim = 200)

Power for predictor 'AQ_centr', (95% confidence interval):
      60.50% (53.36, 67.32)

Test: Kenward Roger (package pbkrtest)
      Effect size for AQ_centr is -0.048

Based on 200 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 153

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 23 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

Is it Cohen's d = -0.048? Or r? What does Kenward Roger test have to do with this?

And then, when I run it for the categorical predictor, there are no effect sizes reported:

```
> model.cnv.cue = lme4::lmer(CNV_500_cue ~  cond + AQ_centr + LSAS_centr + (1 | code), data = ANT, REML = FALSE)
> powerSim(model.cnv.cue,nsim = 200)

Power for predictor 'cond', (95% confidence interval):
      95.50% (91.63, 97.92)

Test: Likelihood ratio

Based on 200 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)

alpha = 0.05, nrow = 153

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 13 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

So how does the package estimate the effect sizes? And how to get effect sizes for categorical predictors?

Answer (score 0):

The effect size `-0.048` is the slope of your predictor `AQ_centr`. 
Kenward Roger tests are used to calculate your p-values for the continuous predictor; for your categorical predictor Likelihood ratio tests are used. Instead of KR you could have also used Bootstrap etc. (it's just the way of computing p-values).
Your 3 level categorical predictor is probably split into 2 dummy variables when entering the model. If you are interested in the effect of one specific dummy variable (let's say `cond2`), you can run a z-test on it, like so:

```
powerSim(model.cnv.cue, fixed('cond2', 'z'), nsim=200)
```

To find out about the dummy variables, you can take a look at the model summary:

```
summary(model.cnv.cue)$coef
```

More info can be found here:

https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12504

https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1111%2F2041-210X.12504&file=mee312504-sup-0001-AppendixS1.html